# Permission Denied when trying to access user file

Tags: python

My Code:

```
import subprocess

def compile_java(java_file):
    cmd = '/Users/myname/Desktop/Java/' + java_file 
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)

compile_java("HelloWorld.java")
```

Error:

```
/bin/sh: /Users/myname/Desktop/Java/HelloWorld.java: Permission denied
```

How to I fix this.

Note: I am using Komodo 8.

Comment: Do you have the execute permission set for the Java? Also java source files have to be compiled before you can execute them.

Comment: You should first use `javac /path/to/file/HelloWorld.java` to compile the java source file and then use `java /path/to/file/HelloWorld` to run the class file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to compile that java file, but you don't have the `javac` bin in the command. Because of this, it thinks you are trying to execute the java file as an executable (but it is source, not compiled).

```
cmd = 'javac /Users/myname/Desktop/Java/' + java_file
```

Comment: I now get: `javac: file not found: /Users/myname/Desktop/Java/HelloWorld.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>` this might be an entirely different issue but Im sure that the file is there.

Comment: forgot to add the @MattWilliamson

Comment: What do you get if you open terminal and type in `javac /Users/myname/Desktop/Java/HelloWorld.java`? Also, just to be sure, make sure the path is correct with `file /Users/myname/Desktop/Java/HelloWorld.java`

Comment: For the `javac` the terminal just pauses for about 5 seconds but no return. It just goes to Macbook-air:... `file` returns `ASCII English text`

Comment: Those sound good to me. I assume you have a `HelloWorld.class` file in that directory now? What if you do `javac -verbose /Users/myname/Desktop/Java/HelloWorld.java `

Comment: It is. A lot of parsing info.

Comment: How about when you do it in the subprocess call?

Comment: I just reproduced it and when I added javac in there it worked. Maybe try `print cmd ` right after the `cmd =` to make sure the string is passed properly. And I would check case sensitivity too.

Comment: Ok I got it to work. The response it the same (or at lest very similar) to `javac -verbose /Users/myname/Desktop/Java/HelloWorld.java`